# What is a high damage infiltrator setup?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've been playing since near release, and I love infiltrator. I know how to play it well, but I always feel like I'm not dealing enough damage fast enough. The rifle you start with is really great, and I've nearly maxed it's damage. The problem with it is ammo and reload time. I understand it's necessary to give it a smaller amount of ammo and slower reloading speed for balancing reasons, but with enemies constantly popping in and out of cover, it's certainly not a DPS weapon. (To me, anyway. I often find that I'm just about to line up a shot, and the enemy dives back into cover, I miss, and I have to reload.)

So, my real question is, what rifle and what armor are the best for an infiltrator character? I imagine using armor that boosts damage (If any armor does.) and combining it with a fast rifle would make for a real badass, especially if you are using maxed tac. cloak. I rely on my heavy pistols a lot, because of ammo capacity and high damage, but it's not good for long corridors or cross-map firefights.

If you could tell me where to find/buy the items, I'd appreciate it, but that isn't necessary. Just the names are all I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the Black Widow with Extended Barrel and Enhanced scope for weapon, this give me high damage and 3 shots, i like the scope for looking through smoke and precision but for more damage you could replace it with a Concentration Mod.

For backup I went with Paladin to keep my Power Recharge speed at a reasonable level while the weapon is still use full.

For gear i use the following to maximise my damage when doing headshots:
[image: armor]

I am currently level 37 and have focused my powers on damage. First i went for Tactical cloak, then Operational Mastery. Sabotage is good to give me some breathing room some times.
[image]

I always pick Liara as a squad made so she can lower the stress by lifting up some hostiles with Singularity if there are allot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm leveling Sabotage myself, but I can't figure out how to use it effectively. How do I select best answers?

Answer (score 2):

Two words: Black Widow.  It's available in the Specter armory.

That will help with the DPS.  It has slightly less damage than the Widow, but has a 3 round thermal clip.  Make sure to equip the Extended Barrel and Concentration mods.

For armor components, go with either Hahne-Kedar for strait up damage boosting or Armax Arsenal for a mix of head shot damage and overall damage boosting.

There's some various headgear options to look into as well: Kuwashii Visor, Recon Hood and Delumcore Visor.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Raptor w/ extended barrel and enhanced scope it has plenty of ammo and fires pretty fast my armour is security interface for helmet chest: Kassa Fabrication Arms: Ariake Technologies Shoulders: Armax Arsenal and for legs I have Armax Arsenal no power bonuses but its good for combat